# SQL: Base Quantity that changes with demand and usage

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a view that calculates the potential material quantities for my company. I'm doing this code in Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

In the view we have a Material Number, a date, demand quantity, received quantity, and an initial quantity.

I have a date listed for when the item demand is needed, and when items are expected to be received. On each listed date, I'd like to know what our inventory will look like for each item. In my head I have determined what I need is the following:

```
CurrentOnHand - DemandQuantity + ReceivedQuantity = NewTotal
```

The new total will move down to the next row and will take the spot of the CurrentOnHand, and the calculation will be performed for each date on the item.

How would I go about achieving this? Do I need to make some sort of running total? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time!

Corey Hall

Comment: There's not enough data (to me) to make a conclusion on this but this is a complex concept of manufacturing that requires a whole lot of tables - are these material quantities built into something else - are they sold - what's they scrap rate - MRP's are expensive because they are complex and require a lot of transaction information.  If you could at least provide a mock up of the database model you're working with it would help

Comment: I agree, we need more data to help you out. Can you show us a set of sample data and possibly your expected outcome?

Comment: I've come up with a round about way to achieve the results I'm looking for. I apologize for not sharing enough information. In the future I will make sure to include more information.